# Cannot authenticate service account on compute engine

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery

The service account json generated file is on the server. I have run the command successfully:

> gcloud auth activate-service-account --project myproj --key-file
>   Myproj-xxxxxxx.json

Authenticating with bigquery

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

But as soon as I make an `execute` on a query I receive the error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproj/jobs?alt=json
>   returned "Invalid credential">

Why does this not work on compute engine?

Also, everything was working fine with p12 key, we're just refactoring to the json auth method. And, *it works on my machine*